# SharePoint Top Navigation CSS issue

Tags: 2010, css, navigation

we have a customise SharePoint 2010 intranet and I have some issue with the top navigation bar. I have created 3 sub sites under Campaigns

[image]

and as you can see in the image the colour in the sub-sites is not consistent, some blank colour there. I have access to CSS file just don't know where to look.

**CSS**

```
.s4-tn-siteslink{
display:block;
float:left;
}
.s4-tn{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}
.s4-tn ul.static{
white-space:nowrap;
}
.s4-tn li.static > .menu-item{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2")] */ color:#3b4f65;
white-space:nowrap;
border:1px solid transparent;
padding:4px 10px;
display:inline-block;
height:15px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: post your current css

Comment: whole CSS or just top navigation section?